# Проблема вызова конструктора

Tags: c++

Файл Logger.h

```
class Logger {
public:
    class LoggerException {
    public:
        explicit LoggerException(char const * stackTrace) {
            this->stackTrace = new char[strlen(stackTrace) + 1];
            strcpy(this->stackTrace, stackTrace);
        }

        char * getStackTrace() {
            return stackTrace;
        }
    protected:
        char * stackTrace;
    };

    class FileNotFoundException : LoggerException {
    public:
        FileNotFoundException() {
            LoggerException("File not found!");
        }
    };

    void openFile() {
        ...
        if(!file) throw FileNotFoundException();
        ...
    }
...
```

Компилятор выдаёт:
In constructor 'Logger::FileNotFoundException::FileNotFoundException()':
error: no matching function for call to 'Logger::LoggerException::LoggerException()'
candidate: Logger::LoggerException::LoggerException(const char*)
candidate: constexpr Logger::LoggerException::LoggerException(const Logger::LoggerException&)
candidate: constexpr Logger::LoggerException::LoggerException(Logger::LoggerException&&)

Comment: `LoggerException("File not found!");` не вызывает конструктор базового объекта, а создает временный безыменный объект

Comment: На будущее: у вас в конструкторе есть `new char[]`, а деструктора, который бы делал `delete [] stackTrace` здесь нет, это может приводить к проблемам

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вызов конструктора предка из потомка выполняется вот так:

```
FileNotFoundException():LoggerException("File not found!") {}
```